# Bash output redirection to sub directory of current directory

Tags: bash

I'm very new to using UNIX/Bash. I'm currently outputting the product of a random number generator to a text file in a subdirectory using the following:

```
./generate > ~/workspace/pset3/find/output/output.txt
```

my current directory in this case would be `find`. Is there a way to type the path such that I can briefly specify a sub-directory of the current directory without typing the full path each time?

Comment: the reference to a subdirectory of the current directory would be `./subdir/filename` or simply `subdir/filename`. Take your pick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the reference to a subdirectory of the current directory would be `./subdir/filename` or simply `subdir/filename`. in your example, if you are in `~/workspace/pset3/find` and address the `output.txt` file, you can reference it as `./output/output.txt` or `output/output.txt`

Answer (score 5):

You specify the path to a desired destination from your working directory, so in your case you could just put:

```
> output/output.txt
```

Paths are always taken from your current/working directory, unless they start with '/' or '~'. In these cases, the rest of the path is relative to the root or your home directory respectively. (There may be other examples of this too)